# Permission for include file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm compiling a Cmake project with Eigen library.

```
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
message("find eigen3" )
message("${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR}" )
```

And the compiling error is:

```
error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
 #include <Eigen/Core>
```

However, the IDE does point to /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core. Is it simply a permission problem? (right now the permission is -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root)

Comment: Don't think so, read/search permissions should be just fine to access include files and link to libraries.

Comment: are you sure you have /usr/include/eigen3 in the include path?

Comment: Check the linker path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the package. For example [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/44140/fatal-error-eigencore-no-such-file-or-directory/) is a discussion of the same or a similar problem. It seems you'll need to also add

```
include_directories(${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${EIGEN_DEFINITIONS})
```